# Google Play Store is not updating

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services

I unistalled Google Play Services and Google Play Store and later when I reinstalled them both, the Google Play Store was again back to an old version, and now it's not updating. Before I uninstalled it was updated to the latest version, the one with material design. I've tried updating it manually in  `Google Play >Settings >Build version` but it says it is up do date. Please  help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is get the .apk file of the Google PlayServices and Google PlayStore from some trusted source like [Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com) etc. You can also use these .apk files [Google Play Store](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/google-play-store-5-0-37-apk/) and 
[Google Play Service](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-6-1-84-1532979-738-apk/) and install it over your device that's should solve the updating problem you are experiencing.